# Django Form is rendered continuously

Tags: django

I have created a model from in django.After rendering the form. the output is continuously displayed. how can i make it in proper way.Like after every field is bellow previous field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User Form Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>USER REGISTRATION FORM</h1>
    <Form action=" "  method="post">
        {{Templateform}}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" name="" value="submit">
        <input type="reset"  name="" value="Reset">
    </Form>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js" %}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `{{Templateform.as_p}}` instead of `{{Templateform}}` it will display fields one after another below each other.